# Porting Mono to .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, mono, porting

I have a project that needs to be done using ASP.NET. Currently, I'm using a Linux box and don't have an access to Windows so I was wondering about doing the development in Mono.Net for the meanwhile. The final project needs to be completed on the Microsoft.NET.

How easy would it be to port a Mono.NET application to a Microsoft.NET? Or should I just wait till I get the windows machine? I don't mind an occasional challenge but not if it's going to be a big pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine just make sure you use the Microsoft .NET APIs only or keep track of any Mono or other opensource DLLs and include them when you run on Windows.

MonoDevelop could also help as it creates Visual Studio compatible project files which can help your migration if you want to later migrate to Visual Studio also.